# Unable to download exe via mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven, repository, http-status-code-401, mvn-repo

I get this error when running `mvn clean install`:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.1:install-node-and-npm (Install NodeJS and NPM binaries) on project Hian-Direct-War: Could not download Node.js from: https://binaries.me.com/artifactory/igi-digital-maven-local/nodejs/v4.4.3/win-x64/node.exe: Got error code 401 from the server. -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
> [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :Hian-Direct-War

I can however log into that URL through my browser and manually download the `.exe`. Is there anything I should do to allow this when running `mvn clean install` via my cmd?

Comment: Sounds like a proxy problem, or maybe firewall. You are probably inside a company network.

Comment: `[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.`